# Can we say we are an adult each?

Tags: each-every

“We have a car” can mean we have a car each. It makes me wonder if I can also apply “each” to a noun complement of a copular verb.

So, can we say “we are an adult each”?

Comment: But “We have a car” ***can't*** normally mean we have a car each. That kind of "one-to-one" sense only really exists in contexts like *We have two ears but only one mouth, which is God's way of telling us we should listen twice as much as we speak,* where real-world facts force us to abandon the default meaning of joint possession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/each), **each** means

> every thing, person, etc. in a group of two or more, **considered separately**

The highlighted bit is quite important. You can say that

> We **each** have a car

because each person, considered separately, has their own car.

When you are saying that a group of people are adults, there is no need to consider them separately because being adult is something that unites them, so you would say

> We are **both** adults - *for two people*
> We are **all** adults - *for three or more people*

---

Note that "we have a car" means that we collectively own just one car.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what you mean when you say

> We have a car

means the same thing as

> We each have a car.

The first means that however many we are, there is one car we share jointly.

The second means that there are multiple cars, one for each of us.

Certainly it is grammatical to say

> We are each an adult

but it may be more idiomaric to say

> We are all adults